# Retrieving large table from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pymysql

I have a very large MySQL database table -- about a billion rows (and some individually large). I'd like to process all of it, row by row, from Python. I'd like to know the best way to do this. I don't need consistency. The table is changing, constantly, but none of that will matter for what I'm doing. I'm wondering the best way to do this.

- `SELECT * FROM TABLE` just sits there.
- I tried partitioning the data. I'd do a series of `SELECT` statements with blocks of IDs (`WHERE ID >= 1,000,000 AND ID < 2,000,000`). This wasn't fast, but it more-or-less worked. It stopped working when there were non-sequential IDs.
- I tried finding appropriate partitions with a thousand statements like: `SELECT ID FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1 OFFSET 100,000,000`. This was very slow for large offsets. I think each such statement involves a sequential walk of the table, judging on performance scaling. Getting a set of partitions this way appears to be a O(n^2) process, which is rather impractical given `n` is a billion.

I'm wondering if there's a good way to stream the whole table of data out with reasonable performance. I can't stop writes to the table (which are coming in at a rate probably around tens per second), but it's okay if I lose consistency on the readout. I think there ought to be some flag to tell MySQL to not be ACID for a given read, but I haven't been able to find it (maybe I'm just failing at Google).

I am **not** an admin on this database, can't make schema changes, etc. It's a production database for a major operation (which it's very well optimized for), where I'm doing a bit of data analytics on the side (which it's not optimized for at all -- I'd like to grab the data and put it in a more appropriate format). I have access to a single read replica (shared with a few other people analyzing such data). I would not have access to create another read replica, or to make this one not follow the production database.

Comment: What do you want to do in Python?  The best method is if you can do all the database processing inside the database.

Comment: I ought to be able to do this in the database, but it's *really* not set up for it. It doesn't have the right indexes. It has writes coming in. Many fields are stored in strings containing JSON. Most operations on the data are estimated to take, literally, months. Etc. It's designed as an operational database which acts essentially as a key-value-store. Doing much beyond that is impractical. If I could ETL this into a different database, with indexes, with many fields shrunk, etc. it'd be plausible. But not where it is. And to do anything, I first need to get a few TB of data out.

Comment: How's the table defined? indexes? column types? Also, offsetting is a NO NO because you have to actually walk all the way to the first record of the batch for every block, so you're running N times a full scan up to the row number...

Comment: get a few TB out?  Just use a python connector and `select * from the_table limit X` in batches that your local RAM and Python can work with easily enough (maybe 1M rows per call, shouldn't take more than 100 or 1000 calls to reach a TB, if it's 1K/row)

Comment: Alfabravo: The table has 11 columns, one of which is 'id' and a primary key. Most of the data is stored in a column which is a varchar(255). There are a few columns which serve as a secondary ID together, but are pretty immaterial to what I'm doing. SlimsGhost: That doesn't work. That would require offsetting, as per Alfabravo's comment, and is O(n^2). All: Right now, I am grabbing that data with an ad-hoc, hand-crafted partition of IDs based on what I know about where the breaks in data are, but that doesn't seem like the right approach. There ought to be some way to do this cleanly.